# Get emails in google spreadsheet in which i am not last sender

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a newbie in coding. Need a little help please.

I want to get last email of the thread, with email address, time, email subject line & email body of the last email of each thread in google sheets.

Can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
function getLastMessageInAThread() {
  const threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for (let i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    const msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    const lastmsg = msgs[msgs.length-1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by saving the email as a draft. Using msg.getFrom() and then sending.

```
function emailTeacher(inStatus, storyTxt, contributorArr)  {
  myLog('Begin emailTeacher - inStatus: ', inStatus);
  const toEmail = 'kleinl@ritenourschools.org';
  let theSubject;
  if ( inStatus = 'good' )  {
    theSubject = 'Contribution' ;
  }    else    {
    theSubject = 'Collision in save';
  }
    
  const date1 = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Mexico_City"}));
  const theBody = 'contributorArr[0] + ' + 
                  '\nStory entered:\n' + storyTxt + 
                  '\n at ' + date1;

  try    {
    GmailApp.createDraft(
       toEmail
      ,theSubject
      ,theBody);
  }    catch(err)    {
    myLog(contributorArr[0] + '  caught in email send: ' + err );  
  }
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  let draft, draftId, msg;
  try    {
    let drafts = GmailApp.getDrafts();
    draft = drafts[drafts.length-1];  // most recent, zero based array        draftId = draft.getId();  
    myLog('draftId: ' + draftId + ' drafts.length: ' + drafts.length );  
    msg = draft.getMessage();
    myLog(contributorArr[0] + '  getFrom(): ' + msg.getFrom() );
    if ( inStatus = 'good' )  {    //  add sender email to ss
      STORY_SHT.getRange(lastRow+1, 7)
               .setValue(msg.getFrom());  
    }
    try    {
      GmailApp.getDraft(draftId).send();
      myLog('email sent draft');
      return true;  //  good
    }    catch (err)     {
      myLog(contributorArr[0] + '  caught in (draftId).send: ' + err ); 
      return false;  //  bad 
    }
  }    catch(err)    {
    myLog(contributorArr[0] + '  caught in getDrafts: ' + err ); 
    return false;  //  bad 
  }

}    //  end function emailTeacher
```